# How to increase limit of 'decimal' field in expressionengine

Tags: expressionengine

I've got a Text Input field with 'Allowed Content' set to 'Decimal'. It won't let me set it to anything over a million on an entry, giving the error `number_exceeds_limit`.

I've thought about saving it as a string rather than use the decimal content type but I need to display them in order using `orderby` on the field and if it is a string it will treat 9 and being greater than 100 since 9 is greater than 1.

Is there a way to either increase or get around the million limit?

Expressionengine version 3.5.2 in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to edit the logic in `cp/ee/EllisLab/Addons/text/ft.text.php` (line 62 in 5.1.2) and also edit the column type in the DB structure (I just tried this locally setting the field length to `20,4` instead of `10,4`.

It is probably worth raising an issue about this on the EE github as that limit seems restrictive to me (mySQL supports 65 digits). https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/issues